# Angular ng-boostrap modal with an embeded video reloads when mouse is moved

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, video, ng-bootstrap

I have an `Angular 7 ng-bootstrap modal` that loads a video player in an `<iframe>`.  A test framework on a local PC works just fine, however when I move the modal to the production system, anytime the mouse is moved, the video is reloaded.

I have tried the following directive to in a attempt to capture the mouse events to stop the propagation, hence preventing the reloading.

```
import { Directive, HostListener } from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
  selector: '[mt2StopMouseEvents]'
})

export class StopMouseEventsDirective {

  @HostListener('mouseover', [ '$event' ])
  public onMouseover(event: any): void {
    console.log(`onMouseOver\t${JSON.stringify(event)}`);
    event.stopPropagation();
  }
  @HostListener('mousemove', [ '$event' ])
  public onMousemove(event: any): void {
    console.log(`onMousemove\t${JSON.stringify(event)}`);
    event.stopPropagation();
  } 
  @HostListener('mouseleave', [ '$event' ])
  public onMouseleave(event: any): void {
    console.log(`onMouseleave\t${JSON.stringify(event)}`);
    event.stopPropagation();
  }
  @HostListener('mousemout', [ '$event' ])
  public onMouseout(event: any): void {
    console.log(`onMouseout\t${JSON.stringify(event)}`);
    event.stopPropagation();
  }
  constructor() { }
}
```

The selector is then added to the modal

```
<div class="modal-content" mt2StopMouseEvents  >
    <div class="modal-header bg-success">
        <h3 class="modal-title  "
        >{{title}}
        </h3>
        <button type="button"
                class="btn btn-light"
                (click)="activeModal.dismiss('Close click')"
        >Close
        </button>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body" >
        <iframe
                height="100%"
                width="100%"
                [src]="getURL()"
        ></iframe>
    </div>
</div>
```

The help model component is as follows:

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input }      from '@angular/core';
import { DomSanitizer, SafeResourceUrl } from '@angular/platform-browser';


import { NgbActiveModal } from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';

@Component({
    selector:    'mt2-help',
    templateUrl: './myHelp.component.html',
    styleUrls:   [ './myHelp.component.scss' ],

})

export class MyHelpComponent implements OnInit {


    @Input() title;
    @Input() helpURL;

    constructor(
        private sanitizer: DomSanitizer,
        public activeModal: NgbActiveModal
    ) { }

    ngOnInit() {
    }

    getURL(): SafeResourceUrl {
        return this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl(this.helpURL);
    }
}
```

The events are captured but the event does not prevent the video reloading. Here is a small sample of the console log.

```
onMousemove  {"isTrusted":true}  stop-mouse-events.directive.ts:26 
onMouseleave {"isTrusted":true}  stop-mouse-events.directive.ts:11 
onMouseOver  {"isTrusted":true}  stop-mouse-events.directive.ts:16
```

As always, thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Well - It turns out that the `lifecycle` hooks were seeing the mouse movement and thus validating the DOM against any changed it found.  To solve this problem I moved the the `url sanitizer` into 'ngOnInit` and saved it as a private variable.  Then returned the variable when requested by the template.  I also removed the directive from the template that I created in my attempt to stop event propagation.

So now the class looks like:

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input }      from '@angular/core';
import { DomSanitizer, SafeResourceUrl } from '@angular/platform-browser';


import { NgbActiveModal } from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';

@Component({
    selector:    'mt2-help',
    templateUrl: './myHelp.component.html',
    styleUrls:   [ './myHelp.component.scss' ],

})

export class MyHelpComponent implements OnInit {


    @Input() title;
    @Input() helpURL;

    private _helpURL: SafeResourceUrl;

    constructor(
        private sanitizer: DomSanitizer,
        public activeModal: NgbActiveModal
    ) { }

    ngOnInit() {
        this._helpURL = this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl(this.helpURL);
    }

    getURL(): SafeResourceUrl {
        return this._helpURL;
    }
}
```

Many thanks to **Max Koretskyi** (aka Wizard) and his article "[A gentle introduction into change detection in Angular](https://blog.angularindepth.com/a-gentle-introduction-into-change-detection-in-angular-33f9ffff6f10)" along with his YouTube [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DsBy9O0c6eo) that pointed me in the right direction.